# jquery Accordion -- collapsible bug

Tags: jquery, accordion

in jQuery  [accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion), we could set collapsible parameter as follow

$("#accordion").accordion({ active: 0 , collapsible: true});

The collapsible behaviour is working fine for the first time.
But subsequently it would give error and stop the whole accordion behaviour.
"this.toHide.parent()[0] is undefined"

Any idea whether this is known bug for this?

Comment: What version of jQuery UI are you using and do you mind showing us some more code?

Comment: Can you paste an example for us on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have found this error today as well. Has there been a code update on the CDNs?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing if I set active:false when initialising. Removing that makes the accordion work again. Did not have this issue yesterday.

Comment: Yes, v1.8.8 has this bug.
Firebug reports:
this.toHide.parent()[0] is undefined Line 230

v1.8.7 works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having this problem using Google for CDN. I used a previous version of the UI code and now it seems to be working. 1.8.8 seems to be causing the error so try using 1.8.7 instead - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Thank you!  Downgrading fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

recent versions of jquery-ui fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

There was definitely an update on the CDNs.. I'm using google, and the 1.8.8 update has broken this. If you are just using /ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js, change it to /ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js

I had the exact same problem and this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Even the demo on their own site is broken!!
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#collapsible
I tried FF and Chrome and it doesn't work in both.